# Multiple Firebase Projects

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm making an app in Flutter but I'm struggling with the thought in the beginning...
It is possible to make a FirebaseOptions load the keys and data from a firebase project, before the self project?
Like...I will set the data of the clients in a collection of my admin project, then the client with their login will access their collections of their project in firebase.
That way, when a new client appear I will add in my admin project, giving access to this new client.

Only to know if this is possible or I'm thinking the wrong way.

Comment: Yes it is possible to access data from different Firebase project in your Flutter app. You can use `FirebaseApp.configure()` method to initialize your Firebase app with different `FirebaseOption` for other Firebase project